# SCOM SDK how to remove client cache

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, dispose, scom

I use C# SCOM SDK to collect our performance and event data to SCOM 1801.

For connection to Management Group I use next code:

```
var settings = new ManagementGroupConnectionSettings(serverName)
{
    //CacheMode = CacheMode.None,
    UserName = userName,
    Domain = domain,
    Password = ToSecureString(password)
};

var managementGroup = ManagementGroup.Connect(settings);
```

All works fine.

But GC does not clean memory after calling `managementGroup.Dispose()` method.

I have reviewed memory using VS memory profile.

And I can see next situation:

[image]

Of course I can disable caching using property `CacheMode=CacheMode.None` for
[ManagementGroupConnectionSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.enterprisemanagement.common.connectionsettings.aspx) class.

But in this case SCOM SDK works very very very slow.

So I think the proper way is to use caching and after necessary work need to delete cache.

**How can I delete the SCOM SDK client cache?**

Comment: Did you call `GC.Collect()` ?

Comment: @Sinatr Yes I do it: `managementGroup.Dispose(); GC.Collect();` But cache is exists. I think we need to run additional SCOM SDK method to clean cache. I have reviewed many documentation links but do not see how I can do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `CacheMode.ManagementPacks` enum value.

More information about CacheMode enum you can find on [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/system-center/developer/bb465460%28v%3Dmsdn.10%29).

I hope it helps.